# Scrolling on ListBox in Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, popup

I have that layout:

```
<Popup>
    <Border>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock/>
                <ListBox/>
                <TextBlock/>
                <ListBox/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

The problem I have is that I can scroll when cursor is above TextBlock and background of border, but I can not when it is above ListBox items.
ListBox display all items without scroll bar.
I want that whole ListBox behave as one control.

Why scrolling don't work only above ListBoxes?

Comment: When you scroll over `ListBox` you scroll that `ListBox`. I assume you are talking about mouse wheel scrolling.

Comment: Have you got a winrt/universal or Windows phone project instead of WPF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by scrolling you mean mouse wheel then it has nothing to do with `ListBox` being in `Popup`. It's because of a `ScrollViewer` which is part of `ListBox` default template. If you want to handle scroll elsewhere you need to remove that `ScrollViewer` by changing `ListBox.Template`

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `ScrollViewer` and `ListBox` support scrolling. 
Your `Grid` will allow all controls within it to expand as much as they can within the dimensions allotted to it. in this case the dimensions are functionally infinite because the `Grid` is encased in a `ScrollViewer`. If you wish for your `ListBox` to scroll and not fully expand you need to either set dimensions on your `Grid`, or get rid of the `ScrollViewer`.

Dimensions set:

```
<Popup>
    <Border>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
                <TextBlock/>
                <ListBox/>
                <TextBlock/>
                <ListBox/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

No `ScrollViewer`:

```
<Popup>
    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock/>
            <ListBox/>
            <TextBlock/>
            <ListBox/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```